# Disable primefaces-extension ckeditor

Tags: primefaces, ckeditor

I use Primefaces extension 3.0.0 with Primefaces 5.2 with no problem.

But i try now to upgrade to Primefaces extension 3.2.0 and i've a problem with ckeditor.

I don't want to use the embed Primefaces extension CkEditor, but a custom one that is in my `webapp/resources` directory. With 3.0.0 all is ok. 
But with the 3.2.0 version, all the GET for needed resources, like plugins, are intercepted by primefaces extension and my custom ckeditor doesn't start. 
I don't want to install the primefaces-extension ckeditor. Just use my own.

I've this errors :

> GET
>   http://localhost:8080/chainedit3/javax.faces.resource/ckeditor/config.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces-extensions&v=3.2.0
>   404 (Introuvable) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'dir' of
>   undefined

The good GET should be :
GET http://localhost:8080/chainedit3/resources/ckeditor/config.js

How can i disable this bad resources GET in primefaces-extension or in ckeditor?

```
<p:panel rendered="#{inputItem.type == 'typeeditor'}" width="75%">  
     <script type="text/javascript" >
            var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH  = '../../resources/ckeditor/';
     </script>
     <script src="../../resources/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"/>
     <script type="text/javascript" >
            CKEDITOR.plugins.basePath = '../../resources/ckeditor/plugins/';
     </script>

     <textarea cols="90" rows="20"  id="editor0" name="0editor">
        #{inputItem.inputItemEditor.value}
     </textarea>

     <script type="text/javascript" >
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor0',
    {
        uiColor: '#85B5D9',
        width: '100%',
        height: '300px',
        readOnly : #{!associateBean.editMode},
        chaineditCKEditorURL : "../../resources/ckeditor",
        mathJaxLib : 'http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML',
        <ui:repeat value="#{inputItem.inputItemEditor.parameters}" 
            var="eAttribute" varStatus="statusAttribute">
            #{eAttribute.value} : #{eAttribute.label},
        </ui:repeat>
        allowedContent : true
    });
    </script>
</p:panel>
```

Comment: The solution for me is finally to write this before calling ckeditor.js to disable pe get url :                   function CKEDITOR_GETURL( resource ){}

Comment: Thanks, @Romuald, you save my life!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I did it the following way:

```
CKEDITOR_GETURL = function (r) {
   return r.startsWith('http:') ? r : "http//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.6/full-all/" + r;
};
```